# Apache Camel - consume messages only if queue size greater than

Tags: java, apache-camel, jms, activemq-classic

I'm trying to find the way of consuming the messages in a ActiveMQ queue only if the count of messages is greater than a certain number.
Any ideas?
Usually if you use the syntax:

```
from("jms:start-queue")
   .process(new SampleProcessor())
   .to("jms:end-queue")
.end();
```

the messages are consumed as soon they are "passed to the processor".

Thanks

Comment: Hi! Welcome to stackoverflow. It would help if you can explain what you are trying to achieve? Are you looking for an overflow processor to deal with backlogs of unprocessed issues, or is there something else? Would you be wanting to retrieve the head or tail of the queue if the queue is greater than X messages?

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible to `aggregate` the messages with a `completionSize` ?

```
from("...")
    .aggregate(constant(true), new MyListAggregator())
    .completionSize(x)
    .to("...")
```

Please see [this articale about aggregation](https://dzone.com/articles/real-time-data-batching-with-apache-camel)

Comment: Youre welcome! Feel free to upvote and accept my answer (green "tick") if you find it useful